# Picture styles not available in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I'm not able to add style to my picture, because the toolbar is not available. In "Customize The Ribbon" window, these options are grayed out. See screenshot:

[image]

How to bring these tools back? I'm using Microsoft Office 365 Business (on Windows 10 PC, desktop app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is an issue with Word if you drag and drop a picture in, rather than copy and paste it or insert it.

There is a [thread here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/picture-styles-is-greyed-out-not-available/c68270a8-ff1e-414b-b96a-9a4b7530103f) detailing it, it may help to copy and paste, or insert the picture instead. This should then allow you to use the toolbar as expected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To fix this click on the picture -> Cut (Strg+X) -> Paste (Srg+V)

Comment: another best option is to.. use Insert -> Picture (menu). Select All Pictures... click on first picture... and hold shift.. and click on last picture.. then do insert. all pictures will be inserted.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and the cause was that my document was opened in [compatibility mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2117661).

To convert the document to current MS Word format and to enable all Word features, click the **Convert** button on the **Info menu**.

Once it was done, the **Picture Styles** options became available.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the old version of the word document. 
You might have installed with the latest word update in your PC,but working on the old template.

[image: Old image(Shows no style while clicking on it)]

Right click the property of the word document

[image: Word document property]

[image: Click on the File option on the top ribbon menu]

There you will see the compatibility mode

[image: Now click convert]

[image: Click OK for this]

Your issue will get resolved

[image: New image shows style option after converting to the compatibility]